# add horizontal lines between each menu texts in magento site

Tags: css, magento

I want to give separation between the list of menus in the site.

How to display horizontal lines between each menu items in this site

I want something like this :

We used the below code in `menu.css`

```
.em-catalog-navigation li { border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece; }
```

Strange thing is that it didn't work for me.

Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: There are lots of menus. Which one do you mean? Can't find the given selector in the HTML.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply.... I want for BOYS TOYS menu....

Comment: Ok, for the sub-menu of Boys Toys it's maybe something like this: `li.menu-item-text li{border-top: 1px solid #cecece;} li.menu-item-text li:first-child{border-top: 0;}`

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply, i will try and let you know soon....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was already a style for the parent li [BOY TOYS] so have used that to target the items you wanted

```
.em_nav .menu-item-hbox .menu-container .menu-item-text.menu-item-depth-3 > ul > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece; 
}
```